# How to protect formulas in a column during JXLS transformation

Tags: java, jxls

[image]

Attached is the snapshot of xlsx which i used to write data using JXLS. however am writing data only in COLUMN 1. but from the downloaded file. the formulas present in column 4 are changed. How do we protect the formulas present in a whole column from jxls transformation.

below is the code snippet i use to write the data.

```
XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
        Workbook destWorkbook = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(templateFile));
            destWorkbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, beans);
        } catch (ParsePropertyException | InvalidFormatException | IOException e) {
            throw new LoyException(e);
        }
        return destWorkbook;
```

I tried locking the cell and protecting the sheet , but it didn't work.

Comment: Jxls-2 should not have this issue. So if you have a possibility just migrate your project to jxls-2

Comment: How do we achieve this functionality in JXLS 2? are there any tags to skip a column from transformation?

Comment: In Jxls-2 you operate on areas so it is easy to process the data by rows or by columns. For example you may choose to process only area A1:B4. In this case columns C and D will not be affected.